# How to join with two tables simultaneously?

Tags: sql

Table `Product`

```
Id name     t1   t2
1  A        1    4
2  B        5    2
3  C        3    1
4  D        4    5
```

Table `Tan`

```
id  tan
1   tanA
2   tanB    
3   tanC
4   tanD
5   tanE
```

I have two above table and i want the result as below in expecting result how it is possible.

Expecting result

```
A   tanA    tanD
B   tanE    tanB
C   tanC    tanA    
D   tanD    tanE
```

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? Also, what is the requirement at all? You haven't provided much informations.

Comment: @myfirstfirst Try  `Select pr.name, j1.tan, j2.tan FROM Product pr join Tan j1 on pr.t1 == j1.id  join Tan j2 on pr.t2 == j2.id  `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join on multiple tables:

```
SELECT p.Name AS ProductName,
       t1.tan AS Tan1,
       t2.tan AS Tan2
FROM dbo.Product p
INNER JOIN Tan t1
    ON p.t1 = t1.id
INNER JOIN Tan t2
    ON p.t2 = t2.id
ORDER BY ProductName ASC
```

[<kbd>**Demo**</kbd>](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/46331/3/0)

Answer (score 0):

You can select from the tan table twice by using a table alias:

```
FROM Product INNER JOIN tan tan1 ON tan1.id = product.t1
             INNER JOIN tan tan2 ON tan2.id = product.t2
```

select the appropriate columns:

```
SELECT Product.name AS name, tan1.tan AS Tan_1, tan2.tan AS Tan_2
```

to give:

```
SELECT product.name AS name, tan1.tan AS Tan_1, tan2.tan AS Tan_2
FROM Product INNER JOIN tan tan1 ON tan1.id = product.t1
             INNER JOIN tan tan2 ON tan2.id = product.t2
```

Comment: Please do not use the outdated and error prone implicit joins in the `where` clause. It's better to use an explicit `JOIN` operator.

Comment: I find it easier to explain it using the implicit joins, but it really is a habit I should get out of...